# "*variable* = Dir" causes error: "Invalid Procedure Call Or Argument" when looping through files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a script that loops through files and vlookups the name into an excel sheet.

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Sub SortVerkoops()
Dim verkoop As String, verkoopnoex As String, gbref As String, orderstatusname As String, gbyear As String, dealer As String, rootorderpath As String, orderpath As String, foldername As String
Dim gbrefv As String
Dim orders As Range
Dim orderstatus As String
Dim wb As Workbook

orderstatusname = Dir("D:\reece\Documents\Sort sales orders into folders\Staff\Order status\Order status 2021.xlsx")

orderstatus = "D:\reece\Documents\Sort sales orders into folders\Staff\Order status\Order status 2021.xlsx"
verkoop = Dir("D:\reece\Documents\Sort sales orders into folders\Staff\Verkoops\*")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=orderstatus, ReadOnly:=True

Set wb = Workbooks(orderstatusname)
Set orders = wb.Sheets("UK Orders").Range("$A:$B")

Do While Len(verkoop) > 0
    Debug.Print "##########"
    Debug.Print verkoop
    verkoopnoex = Replace(verkoop, ".docx", "")
    gbref = Trim(Replace(verkoopnoex, "Sales Order", ""))
    gbyear = Left(gbref, InStr(gbref, "-") - 1)
    gbyear = (gbyear & "-####")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("_gbref") = gbref
    Debug.Print gbrefv
    Debug.Print gbref
    Debug.Print gbyear
    dealer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("_dealer").Value
    Debug.Print dealer
    rootorderpath = ("D:\reece\Documents\Sort sales orders into folders\Staff\Customer orders\" & dealer & "\" & gbyear)
    'foldername = Dir(rootorderpath & "\" & gbref & "*")
    orderpath = (rootorderpath & "\" & foldername)
    Debug.Print foldername
    Debug.Print orderpath
    verkoop = Dir
    Debug.Print verkoop
    Debug.Print "##########"
Loop


End Sub
```

The only trouble I have is when I redefine the variable as = Dir to reset the file, I get this error:

[image: Error message]

The error only shows when this bit of code is active:

[image: Problem code]

I'm having trouble trying to troubleshoot the cause. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Edit 11/06/2021: Massive thanks to [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) for the solution. If anybody would like my working code, let me know and I can clean it up and provide it.

Comment: @BigBen I am looking to look at all the files, check what dealer the gbref corresponds with, find the exact path, then copy the file into that folder and move on to the next one. I know how to do the copying, etc. it’s just that one bit of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest calls to `Dir()` - you must complete one loop before beginning another.

You can instead do something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim colFiles As Collection, fName
    
    Set colFiles = DirMatches("C:\Tester\", "*.xls*")
    For Each fName In colFiles
        Debug.Print fName
    Next fName
    
End Sub

'Run a Dir loop on `FolderPath` and return all matches in a collection
'   of filenames (or full path) where filename matches `pattern` 
Function DirMatches(ByVal folderPath As String, pattern As String)
    Dim col As New Collection, f
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    f = Dir(folderPath & pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        col.Add f                  'filename only
        'col.Add folderPath & f    'full path
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set DirMatches = col
End Function
```

Comment: I have just tested your function and used your loop and it worked an absolute treat. Thank you, my kind sir!